# Задать класс по клику на input тому блоку, класс которого совпадает с id input'a

Tags: javascript, input

Как задать класс `show` по клику на input тому блоку, класс которого совпадает с id input'a?

```css
.click1, .click2 {
  display: none;
}
label {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="click1" type="radio" name="group">
  <span>Кликни по мне</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input id="click2" type="radio"  name="group">
  <span>Или по мне</span>
</label>

<div class="click1">Это - Click1</div>
<div class="click2">Это - Click2</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', fAddClass);

function fAddClass(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') return;
  document.querySelector(`.${ev.target.id}`).classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
label { display: block; }
.click1, .click2 { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="click1" type="radio" name="group">
  <span>Кликни по мне</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input id="click2" type="radio"  name="group">
  <span>Или по мне</span>
</label>

<div class="click1">Это - Click1</div>
<div class="click2">Это - Click2</div>
```

Для скрытия уже показанных блоков:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', fAddClass);

function fAddClass(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') return;
  document.querySelectorAll(`.show`).forEach( el => el.classList.remove('show') );
  document.querySelector(`.${ev.target.id}`).classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
label { display: block; }
.click1, .click2 { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="click1" type="radio" name="group">
  <span>Кликни по мне</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input id="click2" type="radio"  name="group">
  <span>Или по мне</span>
</label>

<div class="click1">Это - Click1</div>
<div class="click2">Это - Click2</div>
```

Пользовательский атрибут в селекторе:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', fAddClass);

function fAddClass(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') return;
  document.querySelectorAll(`.show`).forEach( el => el.classList.remove('show') );
  document.querySelector(`[data-select="${ev.target.id}"]`).classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
label { display: block; }
.click1, .click2 { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="click1" type="radio" name="group">
  <span>Кликни по мне</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input id="click2" type="radio"  name="group">
  <span>Или по мне</span>
</label>

<div data-select="click1" class="click1">Это - Click1</div>
<div data-select="click2" class="click2">Это - Click2</div>
```

Comment: я бы ещё скрывал лишний `div`. Но судя по вопросу, это не требуется

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov: именно так. Строго в рамках вопроса.

Comment: Благодарю!
Подскажите, чтобы как сказал комментатор выше, при выборе другого input скрывался старый div что требуется прописать? Пока что не силен в чистом JS...

Comment: @QuickBrownFox: Добавил вариант.

Comment: Подскажите, а если сравнивать не класс с ID, а какой-либо кастомный атрибут и ID, например, data-select=""

Comment: @QuickBrownFox: просто указать нужный селектор. Дополнил вариантом.